# Ubuntu 16.04 won't shut down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Since I updated the computer to 16.04 I am having random problems shutting down the system. After the "Reached target Shutdown," the computer freezes.

```
[OK] Reached target Shutdown
[168024.082599] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[168024.084833] ata3.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00;00;00;00;00/a0 tag 20 pio 16392 in
[168024.084833]          Get event status notification 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00res 40/00
[168024.089428] ata3.00: status { DRDY }
[168029.410684] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
```

Any help, please?